# Store filename and objectid tuple in collection or query direct using the filename

Tags: c#, mongodb, mongodb-query, gridfs

Currently I'm struggeling with querying data from a `MongoDB GridFS` by using the filename.

**Current situation**

I'm uploading data to the MongoDB by using a `GridFSBucket` and `UploadFromBytesAsync` which returns an `ObjectId` for referencing the data and takes a `filename` as parameter.

**The Problem**

The oposit of `UploadFromBytesAsync` is `DownloadAsBytesAsync` which should be used for querying the data from `GridFS`. But this method only accepts an `ObjectId` and not the *unique* `filename` which is also passed when using `UploadFromBytesAsync`. But I want to query the data by using the `filename`.

**Possible solution**

My Idea was, to create a collection, which stores the `GridFS ObjectId` and `GridFS filename`, to map them. So when querying data, i will search for the `filename` in the collection and then using the `ObjectId` to get the bytes from `GridFS`. The `filename` property would also get an index.

Or should I directly query from `GridFS` using the unique `filename`? And is the `filename` indexed than?

**EDIT!**

Oh, i think the problem is solved by using `DownloadAsBytesByName`.
Thank you very much!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As long as file names are unique - you can use **get** by file name.

To ensure there is only one file, you can use storage option: **OverWrite**

You can create index on fs collection to include fileName field.

-- edit
the call with overwrite loos like:

```
_db.GridFS. Upload(OverWrite(fileName, binaryStream))
```

Comment: Hey, thank you for your answer. How to set `OverWrite`? Could not find a lot anout this.